# How to configure pycharm / intellij idea to run tox tests

Tags: python, testing, intellij-idea, pycharm, pytest

Is it possible to configure pycharm / intellij idea to run tox tests? I want to test my code against different python versions in separated py environments. I was trying to configure it, but so far I only managed to configure single py.test support.

Comment: I'm afraid it's not supported, PyCharm will use the configured interpreter to run the tests. You are welcome to [submit a feature request](http://youtrack.jetbrains.net/issues/PY).

Answer (score -1, accepted):

**UPDATE**: This feature is available since 2016.1 release, [see this blog post](https://blog.jetbrains.com/pycharm/2016/03/announcing-general-availability-of-pycharm-2016-1/) for more details.

---

Original answer from 2013:

<del>I'm afraid it's not supported, PyCharm will use the configured interpreter to run the tests.</del>

Comment: It's supported now in the latest PyCharm Release, >2016.1
[Blog entry](https://blog.jetbrains.com/pycharm/2016/03/announcing-general-availability-of-pycharm-2016-1/)

Answer (score 2):

See this PyCharm issue: [PY-9727](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/PY-9727)

Credit goes to `Andrey Vlasovskikh` at PyCharm

As a workaround, you can create a Python file in your project that imports and launches Tox:

```
import tox
tox.cmdline()
```

and then run this file via your project interpreter using its context menu.

You'll get hyperlinks in the console output for stack traces, but nothing more.

Answer (score 1):

7 years passed and now you can run Tox inside PyCharm. If you use pytest for testing it will even show Test Result same way like with running test locally by PyCharm.

To run tests in pycharm I use config like this

```
[tox]
envlist = py3.{7,8},codestyle,flake8,lint
minversion = 3.7

[testenv]
usedevelop = true
deps =
  pytest
  pytest-cov
commands = pytest --cov=src

[testenv:codestyle]
deps = pycodestyle
commands = pycodestyle src tests

[testenv:flake8]
deps = flake8
commands = flake8 src tests

[testenv:lint]
deps = pylint
commands = pylint src tests --rcfile=.pylintrc
```

[Here](https://lukeonpython.blog/2020/10/tox-pycharm-integration/) I described why it looks like this. Also, there is integration with GitHub CI to run it on every push.